# React settimeout in useeEffect is called every time I navigate back

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I'm trying to change the style of an element within setTimeout and useEffect.

Here is how the code looks like

```
In home.js: 
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        // change styles  for 'frontenddevelopment'
        changeStyles1();
    },1000)

    // changeStyles for 'i love frontend'
    changeStyles2()
},[])
```

I found that after the home page is rendered if I navigate to other pages and come back to home page, changesStyles1() will be called again and animation will run again. What should I do to avoid calling setTimeout() again when I navigate back to home page from other pages.

You will notices that changeStyle2 won't be animated again if I navigate from home page to other page and then back to home page. And this is the effect I want.

My website is hosted on [netlify](https://portfolio-test-1.netlify.app/)
My code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Beemo-007/pen/GRZQzjK)

Comment: can you please supply the component tree?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the timer, otherwise, you may experience adverse side effects in your code.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
        // change styles  for 'frontenddevelopment'
        changeStyles1();
    }, 1000)

    // changeStyles for 'i love frontend'
    changeStyles2()
    
    //clear the timer
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);

},[]);
```

see this [link](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would manage it from the parent component.

Lets assume the following component tree:

- App

  - Home
  - Page1

In App:

```js
const [isFirstMount, setFirstMount] = useState(true);
//...
return(
  <Home ...props changeStyle={isFirstMount} onStyleChanged={() => 
       setFirstMount(false)}/>
  //...
)
```

In Home:

```js
if (props.changeStyle) {
  let pnt = setTimeout(()=>{
    // change styles  for 'frontenddevelopment'
    changeStyles1();
    onStyleChanged()
    clearTimeout(pnt);
   }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have tried this part, i just realized react app won't rendered the updated css style if I setMounted to global state.

Comment: So this is a tricky issue. If home page is rendered, and isMounted is set to be true in app.js. Then navigate back to home page from other page will lose the updated css styles. At this point, in app.js, isMounted will tell home.js don't call changeStyles()

Comment: we need to see the code to help. could you please upload the relevant parts to CodeSandbox and make sure it is working?